# D2: How to explicitly instantiate a templated function in a DLL?

Tags: templates, dllexport, d

I have a D2 type templated function:

```
void AddToAry( InTy, AcTy )( in InTy[] InAry,  ref AcTy[] AcAry )  {    

    for( uint i=0; i<InAry.length; i++ )  AcAry[i] += InAry[i];                     
}
```

I wish to explicitly instantiate it such that this functions code is 
exported by the DLL, for different arg type combinations.

My attempt to do this with three conforming function decorations..

```
export {
    void  AddToAry( float,  float  );
    void  AddToAry( float,  double );
    void  AddToAry( double, double );
}
```

But an attempted compile yields..

```
AccumAry_DLL.d(37): Error: function AccumAry_DLL.AddToAry conflicts with   template AccumAry_DLL.AddToAry(InTy,AcTy) at AccumAry_DLL.d (23)
```

How does one tell the D2 dmd compiler to instantiate and then export the appropriately typed code from the DLL?   ..
  Or perhaps one need to use a D2 mixin template instead ?

For now my work around is to use explicitly typed proxy function. To do so
I renamed the templated generic function to not conflict, and then export the explicitly instantiated proxies like this:

```
export {  // Hopefuly these proxy functions will be "inlined", and ther is no real forwarding overhead.
    void AddToAry( in  float[] InAry,  ref  float[] AcAry )  { _AddToAry( InAry, AcAry ); }
    void AddToAry( in  float[] InAry,  ref double[] AcAry )  { _AddToAry( InAry, AcAry ); }
    void AddToAry( in double[] InAry,  ref double[] AcAry )  { _AddToAry( InAry, AcAry ); }
}  // end export
```

This works, Then I'm asking if there is a way to make sure the D@ compiler does not construct the proxy's additional level of forwarding overhead?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose

`void  AddToAry!( float,  float  )( in float[], ref float[] );`

should work, similar to C++.
You are trying to declare non-template functions - their signature obviously conflicts with your template.

P.S. Not checked, just guessing for now.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to ensure that inlining happens is to simply use a string mixin here. (Template mixins are not really applicable since they introduce a declaration, while you need to introduce a statement.)

```
private enum _AddToAry = `for(size_t i = 0; i < InAry.length; i++)  AcAry[i] += InAry[i];`
extern 
{
    void AddToAry( in  float[] InAry,  ref  float[] AcAry )  { mixin(_AddToAry); }
    void AddToAry( in  float[] InAry,  ref double[] AcAry )  { mixin(_AddToAry); }
    void AddToAry( in double[] InAry,  ref double[] AcAry )  { mixin(_AddToAry); }
}
```

Note that this relies on the fact that the argument naming is consistent. If, however, you need/want to change that up, you can create a simple function that takes the names of the arguments and returns an appropriate string.